# Flipping three consecutive heads then program exits using RandomGenerator

Tags: java, random

I'm stuck on a problem that I don't know how to solve. I'm trying to use the RandomGenerator to simulate flipping a coin until the RandomGenerator flips 3 consecutive heads then at which point the program exits.

Variable flipCounter tracks the total number of flips and variable headsFlip tracks the consecutive heads that are flipped. The if condition says if the flip was heads start the headsFlips counter up to 3 but if the next flip is tails  headsFlips resets to zero.

When i run the program it just prints the last statement in my run method and does not even run the while loop. I don't know why the program isn't working as I expect it to work.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class HeadsFlipThreeInARow extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run(){

 int flipCounter = 0; 
 int headsFlip = 0; 

 while (headsFlip == 3){

 String flip = coinFlip();
 println(flip);

  if (flip.equals("heads")){
    headsFlip += 1;
  }else{
    headsFlip = 0;
  }

 flipCounter++;
 flip = coinFlip();
 } /* end of while loop  */
 println("It took " + flipCounter + "flips to reach 3 consecutive heads.");
 } /* end of run method */


private String coinFlip (){
String flip = rgen.nextBoolean() ? "heads" : "tails";
return flip; 

}

private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that a `while` loop continues as long as the condition is `true`. This means that

```
while (headsFlip == 3)
```

will only execute the body of the loop as long as `headsFlip` is `3`. Since the first time the loop starts, `headsFlip` is `0`, the loop is not executed.

To fix this, change the condition to

```
while (headsFlip < 3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple concept I don't know why I got so confused

Comment: Jessica, you ought to accept one of the very good answers that volunteered their time to make this clear to you.  Your thanks might be nice, but voting up and accepting the best answer is what you need to do.

Comment: @duffymo Easy, dude. She has already got a bunch of accepted questions, so clearly she knows the drill. She might not have 6-figure rep like you, but that doesn't mean you have to condescend her as if she's a noob.

Comment: Easy?  Do you consider that wording abusive?  You need to get out more.  Your skin is too thin.  It's merely a statement.  I expect somebody with a 5 figure rep to know how to not sound like a tool.

Comment: @duffymo Your attitude is toxic. It's not a matter of "getting out more" and/or "too thin-skinned"; if someone in my team has that attitude, I'd get rid of them very quickly (no matter how skilled of a programmer they otherwise are). There's no need, and no place, for insults and condescension among professionals (and professional programmers in particular).

Comment: Read it again - it wasn't insulting or condescending, it was a mere statement to point that thanks were nice but we vote here.  You wouldn't have to get rid of me - I'd never work for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
while (headsFlip == 3){
```

shouldn't this be

```
while (headsFlip < 3){
```

Comment: As i understand it the while loop continues until it's condition becomes false. So shouldn't it be while(headsFlip == 3) and not while(headsFlip < 3) ? Still having trouble grasping the concept

Comment: That's correct, but `while(headsFlip == 3)` is false on the first iteration.

Comment: @JessicaM. `0 == 3` is `false` but `0 < 3` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks I'm still thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, just curious, but wouldn't you need to change the else part from:

```js
 if (flip.equals("heads")){
    headsFlip += 1;
  }else{
    headsFlip = 0;
  }
```

```js
else {
  headsFlip -= 1
```

Otherwise the while loop would exit as soon as you reached three heads but not necessarily three heads in a row, which can really change your result.